# PHP how to manipulate variable inside a for loop and return it

Tags: php, php-7.2

I have declared an array $data and passed it in the parameter for the foreach loop.  inside the loop i need to push or merge the new array and return it.  apparently the return object is not the as expected. it only contains the header.  I'm using php7.2

```
$data = ['code','name'];
    $submission->contributions->each(function (Contribution $contribution) use ($data) {

        $rowData = [
            $contribution->employment->employer->code,
            $contribution->employment->employee->last_name,
        ];

        $data = array_merge($data, [$rowData]);
    });
    print_f($data)
```

Comment: try `use (&$data)`.

Comment: Which library/framework do you use? What is the type of `contributions`? Perhaps there's some function like `reduce` or smth like that which is similar to `array_reduce`, then there won't be any problem to do what you want.

Comment: Im using laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could just use `foreach`, and your `$data` array will be available:

```
$data = ['code','name'];
foreach($submission->contributions as $contribution) {
    $data = array_merge($data, 
        [
            $contribution->employment->employer->code,
            $contribution->employment->employee->last_name
        ]);
}
```

Comment: Great, no problem :)